# Remove match characters before output

Tags: c++, regex

My regex already works well but I would like to remove the " character at the output. Is this possible with Regex?

**Regex:** `(?>\".*?\")`
**Link:** https://regex101.com/r/G7OQ0a/2/

> "SharedKeys" = "0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9"
>   "BroadCastKeys" = "0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9"
>   "A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z"
>
> "ProgramPath" = "D:\Games\WoW\World of Warcraft\Wow.exe"

**Match:** "BroadCastKeys" or "L" and so on

**My target:** BroadCastKeys or L and so on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with this pattern:

```
(?!\G)"\K[^"]*
```

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/N9qnnx/2/)

The idea it to skip the position of the closing quote (without consuming it with the pattern). To do that `(?!\G)` forbids the matches to be consecutive. (`\G` matches the position of the last successful match or the start of the string).

Note that if your string may start with a double quote, you need to change the pattern to `(?!\G(?!\A))"\K[^"]*` to allow the first match.

---

You can also make it more simple and use a capture group:

```
"([^"]*)"
```

Comment: I try to understand. Thank you. very nice!

Comment: Important would be to escapen the upper example. \" Maybe this not relevant in all programming languagues.

Comment: @ivorysmoker: To be clear it isn't relevant since I show the pattern, not the pattern string, and the quote isn't a regex special character (in any language). But if you want  the pattern string, add the tag for the corresponding language to your question.

Comment: The plattern dont work on c++ any idea why maybe? I added c++ Tag. Im use <regex>.

Comment: @ivorysmoker: the c++ regex library use ICU regex flavor, (that's why adding the language tag is essential in regex question). To have the pcre features like `\G` and `\K` you need to use libboost or libpcre. Note that the second pattern will work with any flavor.

Comment: Ok, Thank you for your efforts.